# SetWaitableTimer and daylight saving adjustments

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, dst

For the purpose of a mini-scheduler inside my app I need to be able to schedule an event at some absolute local time.

For instance, I may want to schedule it for `7 AM` on `November 5, 2017`. As anyone living in US probably knows, that is the night when the daylight saving ends at `2 AM`.

So I use the following method:

```
//ERROR CHECKS ARE OMITTED FOR BREVITY
HANDLE hTimer = ::CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

//Nov 5, 2017 at 7:00 AM
SYSTEMTIME stLocal = {2017, 11, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0};
SYSTEMTIME stUTC = {0};
::TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(NULL, &stLocal, &stUTC);

FILETIME ftUTC = {0};
::SystemTimeToFileTime(&stUTC, &ftUTC);

//Set timer
::SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, (LARGE_INTEGER*)&ftUTC, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE);

//Wait for it
::WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);

::CloseHandle(hTimer);
```

Since the `SetWaitableTimer` API takes time in `UTC` form, the method above will be off by 1 hour because of the local-to-UTC conversion done before DST commences on Nov. 5th.

So assuming any arbitrary absolute time for the timer, how do you factor in the daylight saving adjustment?

Comment: The remarks section on msdn for the TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime API states: _TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime takes into account whether daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for the local time to be converted._ Your first argument is NULL meaning _If lpTimeZoneInformation is NULL, the function uses the currently active time zone._ So, if the system has information about the DST offset at your desired local time, it will take that into account. What result do you expect to get and what do you actually get?

Comment: @R.Beiboer: It takes into account the DST offset for when I call `TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime` API. So for instance, if I call it now the DST adjustment will be `UTC-08:00`. This will change on Nov. 5, 2017 to `UTC-07:00` that will throw my timer 1 hr off if I set it now.

Comment: What is your current time zone name? What UTC time do you get for your local 7 AM at 2017 Nov 5, and what would you expect to get? It is easier for me to check the behaviour with the actual data you have.

Comment: @R.Beiboer: I'm not doing it for any specific time zone or time.

Comment: Well, you are passing a specific time in your question, and you are passing NULL as the first argument. That means that you are using the time zone setting of your user account. What is that time zone? And what utc time do you get in the example you gave us in the question, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: The fact that msdn states that it takes the currently active time zone when you pass NULL, does not mean that it will use the currently active DST offset. The remarks section explicitly tells you it will take into account the DST offset that is in use at the specified local time. If you see different results, please show us the data I asked for. Then we can verify it.

Comment: Windows knows when DST starts and ends for a given time zone. Passing NULL just means to use the current active time zone. `TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime()` can easily compare the local time being converted to know if it crosses DST boundaries and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: ... of course, that assumes that the government hasn't changed the rules without notice, but there's not much you or anyone else can do about that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to change your code to factor in the daylight saving adjustment, the [TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485(v=vs.85).aspx) API will already do that for you.

Please note that for future timestamps, the data Windows has for the DST->STD (and vice versa) transitions may be inaccurate. The government may choose to use a different moment for that in the future. Also, sometimes a government may choose to use a whole different time zone, that has happened! For timestamps in the past you probably will get good results, but you will never know how complete Windows' database is.

So, you don't have to change your code, but be aware of the fact that you still may get inaccurate results.

Comment: Well, I've got a report from a user of my software who claims that the schedule fired one hour off on his XP machine during the day when DST adjustment took place. How do you explain that?

Comment: Perhaps that XP machine is lacking information about the DST/STD info for  the specific time? Any idea about the time zone your user is using?

Comment: Did it only happened once? Was it working correctly afterwards? Be aware of the fact then when DST starts you have a "limbo hour", an hour that no UTC time exists for. When standard time starts, you will have an hour that has two UTC times. Could it be that the timer was set to any of these hours?

Comment: Please take look at [Why Daylight Savings Time is nonintuitive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031024-00/?p=42053/)

Comment: I don't have any of that information. Although I would assume that the person's clock was alright in the computer. But that's again, my assumption.